# Find an explicit formula for the solution of the boundary value problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $D$ be the disk of radius $1$ centered at $(0,0)$. Find an explicit formula for the solution of the boundary value problem

$\Delta u=0$ in $D$

$u=x_1^2$ on $\partial D$

I just don't even know how to start this . I feel like I am just missing something obvious.

Comment: Hint: $x_1^2 = \cos^2\theta = (1+\cos2\theta)/2$ on the boundary. Do you know the general form of harmonic functions in polar coordinates?

Comment: Actually in the usual polar coordinates that would be $x_1^2 = \cos^2 \theta$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks, fixed.

Comment: Do you mean the Laplacian in polar coordinates? In that case, yes.

Comment: I mean this: $\sum r^n (A_n \cos n\theta+B_n\sin n\theta)$.